# Lottery App - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python version 3.7.3 , my program has no error but post execution it gives me attribute error (AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'intersection')

```
import random

def menu():
        user_numbers = get_player_numbers
        lottery_numbers = create_lottery_numbers
        matched_numbers = user_numbers.intersection(lottery_numbers)

        print("You matched {} . You won ${}!".format(matched_numbers , 100 ** len(matched_numbers)))


def  get_player_numbers() :
      number_csv = input ("Enter your 6 numbers , separated by commas : ")
      # create a set of integers from this number_csv
      number_list = number_csv.split(",")
      integer_set = {int(number) for number in number_list}
      return integer_set


    def create_lottery_numbers():
          values = set([])
          while len(values) < 6 :
                  values.add(random. randint(1,20))
          return values

    menu()
```

## expect output to execute program as intended

Comment: to call parameter-less function, you need to use `()`. e.g. `user_numbers = get_player_numbers()`

Comment: In addition to @Adam.Er8: You assign the function the your variables. Not their return value. That's legal and indeed no error.